# De-overlapping intervals

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals, overlap

I'm trying to write some code to de-overlap (open) intervals. I found inspiration in [Algorithm to shift overlapping intervals until no overlap is left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205662/algorithm-to-shift-overlapping-intervals-until-no-overlap-is-left) and [Possible Interview Question: How to Find All Overlapping Intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals?rq=1).

Intervals represent physical entities. Their position was estimated by some means, but this imperfect estimate results in overlapping positions of these physical entities. However, in reality these physical entities cannot occupy the same space, so I'm using this code to readjust their positions. This adjustment should move these physical entities as little as possible and maintain their estimated relative positions as much as possible. Since these are physical entities, the length of each interval cannot change.

Code works well in most cases but hangs in some cases like this:

```
intervals = [(0, 8), (9, 13), (11, 14), (15, 21)]
```

Here's my python code. Any suggestions?

```
def intervalLength(interval):
'''
Finds the length of an interval, supplied as a tupple
'''
return interval[1]-interval[0]

def findOverlappingIntervals(intervals):
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542892/possible-interview-question-how-to-find-all-overlapping-intervals?rq=1
# Throw the endpoints of the intervals into an array, marking them as either start- or end-points.
# Sort them by breaking ties by placing end-points before start-points if the intervals are closed, or the other way around if they're half-open.
'''
Takes a list of intervals and returns the intervals that overlap.
List returned has nested list composed of the intervals that overlap with each other
Assumes list is ordered by the start position of the intervals
'''
end_points = []
for n,i in enumerate(intervals):
    end_points.append((i[0],'b',n)) #'b' = beginning of interval
    end_points.append((i[1],'e',n)) #'e' = end of interval
end_points.sort()
b = 0
e = 0
overlapping = [set()]
open_intervals = set()
for ep,sORe,i in end_points:
    if sORe == 'b':
        b += 1
        open_intervals.add(i)
        if b-e > 1 and i in open_intervals:
            overlapping[-1].update(open_intervals)
        elif len(overlapping[-1]) > 0:
            overlapping.append(set())
    else:
        e += 1
        open_intervals.remove(i)

overlapping = [o for o in overlapping if len(o) > 0]
overlapping = [[intervals[i] for i in o] for o in overlapping]

return overlapping

def deOverlap(intervals):
'''
Takes a list of overlapping intervals and returns a new list with updated postions
without overlap and intervals separated by 1, maintaining the previous center
'''
# Find center of overlapping intervals
avg = (reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [a+b for a,b in intervals])+len(intervals)-1)/(len(intervals)*2.0)

# Find the total length of the ovrlapping intervals
tot_length = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [intervalLength(i) for i in intervals]) + len(intervals) - 1

# Find new start position for the overlapping intervals
new_start = int(round(avg-(tot_length/2.0)))

# Place first interval in new position
non_over_intervals = [(new_start, new_start+intervalLength(intervals[0]))]

# Place rest of intervals in new positions
for i in intervals[1:]:
    start = non_over_intervals[-1][1]+1
    non_over_intervals.append((start,start+intervalLength(i)))

return non_over_intervals

def deOverlapIntervals(intervals):
'''
Takes a list of intervals and returns a list with the same intervals with no overlap and
located as close to the original locations as possible
'''
non_over_intervals = intervals
i = 0
while len(findOverlappingIntervals(non_over_intervals)) > 0:
    if i >= 10000:
        print 'Tried 10,000 times and did not finish de-overlapping. Returning best I could do'
        return non_over_intervals
    overlapping_intervals = findOverlappingIntervals(non_over_intervals)
    non_over_intervals = set(non_over_intervals) - set([oi for group in overlapping_intervals for oi in group])
    for oi in overlapping_intervals:
        non_overlapping = deOverlap(oi)
        non_over_intervals.update(non_overlapping)
    non_over_intervals = list(non_over_intervals)
    non_over_intervals.sort()
    i += 1
return non_over_intervals
```

These intervals run fine

```
intervals = [(-5,-1), (0,6), (7,11), (9,14), (12,17), (21,24), (27,32), (32,36), (39,41)]
```

These don't. They hang because intervals keep shifting and overlapping with the left or the right end

```
intervals = [(0, 8), (9, 13), (11, 14), (15, 21)]

non_over_intervals = deOverlapIntervals(intervals)
```

Comment: For the working case is [(-6, -2), (-1, 5), (6, 10), (11, 16), (17, 22),(23, 26), (27, 32), (33, 37), (39, 41)]. For the non-working case it should be [(0, 8), (9, 13), (14, 17), (18, 24)]. My goal is to de-overlap intervals while maintaining the resulting positions and the relative position between intervals as close to the original as possible.

Comment: I do not understand how "de-overlapping" `[(0, 8), (9, 13), (11, 14), (15, 21)]` would result in `[(0, 8), (9, 13), (14, 17), (18, 24)]`.  Maybe you can edit the question to explain much, much more clearly what this means.  For example, given that the input ends at `21`, how on earth does the result end at `24`?

Comment: This does not make any sense to me.  How does your working case include -6, and how does the non-working case include 24?  Those seem to be outside of the ranges provided.

Comment: So, your plan is to increase the value of the following numbers if there is overlapping. The first value of the following interval is `min(item[n][1] + 1, item[n+1,0])`?

Comment: This would preserve the starting position of the whole set of overlapped intervals, but this wouldn't preserve the relative position of these overlapped intervals with other intervals that are not overlapping. That's why I'm going through the trouble of writing this more complicated code, which will adjust leftwards and rightwards to maintain the center of the overlapped intervals (as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205662/algorithm-to-shift-overlapping-intervals-until-no-overlap-is-left.

Comment: When asking questions about data transforms, it's often best to provide a series of test cases: Input, Desired-Output; Input2, Desired-Output2; ... De-overlapping intervals by combining them is easy. You seem to be doing some sort of "removing overlap by shifting." A handful of crisp examples would make that clearer up-front, making for a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if shifting an interval will make it overlap with another interval, then including both the original overlapping intervals and the intervals that would overlap with the shift in a single deOverlapIntervals run will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it a lot more simply?  Like this:

```
result = intervals[:1]

for begin, end in intervals[1:]:
    if begin <= result[-1][1]:
        result[-1] = (result[-1][0], end)
    else:
        result.append((begin, end))
```

Comment: My goal is to de-overlap intervals while maintaining the resulting positions and the relative position between intervals as close to the original as possible. The length of each interval should not change. The list of intervals I provided is part of a longer set of intervals, so the rest of the code helps in identifying overlapping intervals and de-overlap multiple subsets of overlapping intervals. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
intervals = [(0, 8), (9, 13), (11, 14), (15, 21)]
intervals = [list(t) for t in intervals]

for i in range(len(intervals) - 1):
    offset = intervals[i + 1][0] - intervals[i][1]
    if offset < 1:
        diff = intervals[i + 1][1] - intervals[i + 1][0]
        intervals[i + 1][0] = intervals[i][1] + 1
        intervals[i + 1][1] = intervals[i + 1][0] + diff

print(intervals)
```

Comment: Thanks Klaus. This assumes that the position of the first interval in a set of overlapping intervals the most accurate and then shifts the second interval over to the right. A related problem is that if shifting one interval then makes it overlap with another interval on the right and so on, then intervals will continue shifting to the right. However, I want to be more precise and maintain the original positions as much as possible, by shifting things left and right.